# How to get the data from linked servers using queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a `linkedserver` as `ravikiran-vm` which is the virtual machine in my desktop.

Now I have a database called `kiran` which contains an `employ` table.
To retrieve `employ` data, I do the following:

```
select * from ravikiran-vm.kiran.employ
```

but it shows the error "Incorrect syntax near '-'."

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks guys with ur support it working fine...
Now i hav to schedule this as a new job.when i execute it as normal it shows o/p.
but when i cinfigure the same query as sqlserver agent job it gives error and query not executing...Plz help me in this regard

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16):

I think you should change the name of the linked server, as the - char is reserved in SQL.

You could try surrounding the name with brackets, but it becomes boring

Also, you should include the schema name in the query, or double point to use the default one:

so, you can try:

```
select * from [ravikiran-vm].kiran.dbo.employ
select * from [ravikiran-vm].kiran..employ
```

Or whatever your schema be.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([ravikiran-vm],'SELECT * FROM KIRAN..EMPLOY')
```

Comment: Yep. This was the only way I could do it. Thank you. Saved me hours!

Answer (score 2):

to get data from linked server you use 4 part notation
Server.Database.Schema.Table

since you have an invalid character in your name(-) you need to add brackets around the name

```
select * from [ravikiran-vm].kiran..employ
```

You probably also don't want all the data returned

Answer (score 0):

Usually direct queries should not be used in case of linked server because it heavily use temp database of SQL server. At first step data is retrieved into temp DB then filtering occur. There are many threads about this. It is better to use open **OPENQUERY** because it passes SQL to the source linked server and then it return filtered results e.g.

SELECT *  FROM  OPENQUERY(Linked_Server_Name ,  'select * from TableName where ID = 500')

Answer (score 0):

```
1- Link the server

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'OracleSvr', 
'Oracle 7.3', 
'MSDAORA', 
'ORCLDB'


2-SELECT
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(OracleSvr, 'SELECT name, id FROM albert.titles')

3-UPDATE 
UPDATE OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM albert.titles WHERE id = 101') 

4-INSERT
INSERT OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM albert.titles')
VALUES ('NewTitle');

5-DELETE
DELETE OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM albert.titles WHERE name = ''NewTitle''')
```

i just copied from here (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic916320-392-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from likedservername.databasename.dbo(schema).tablename
```

Ex1:

```
select * from [Bse].[Bse].[dbo].Binary

Else

Select * from openquery (linkedservername, 'select * from databasename.dbo(schema).tablename');
```

Ex2:

```
select * from openquery ([Bse], 'select * from [Bse].[dbo].Binary');
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?