# SQL - Connect to Linked Server with Named Instance

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, named-instance

How do I connect to a named instance of a linked SQL server.

If its not linked, I would do the following:

```
ServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

If it is linked, I would assume the following:

```
ServerName\InstanceName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

but SQL doesn't like the "\"

What is the correct syntax

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793827/how-to-get-the-data-from-linked-servers-using-queries/793836#793836)

You can surround server name with brackets

Answer (score 2):

the correct syntax is `[ServerName\InstanceName].DatabaseName.dbo.TableName`.

Comment: I get this: "Could not find server 'ServerName\InstanceName' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default instance, you don't need to specify the instance name.

Example using the default instance:
[MyServer].[MyDatabase].[MySchema].[MyTable]

NB: If you don't know your schema name, give [dbo] a try, since that is the default schema.

So something like this should work for you

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] t
INNER JOIN [MyLinkedServer].[MyLinkedDatabase].[MyLinkedSchema].[MyLinkedTable] lt ON lt.Id = t.Id
```