# How to use openquery in c#

Tags: c#, database-connection, openquery

I have an openquery SQL script:

```
Select * from openquery([oak],'
SELECT LicenseKey, SUM(PaymentAmount)as Payments
FROM vw_ODBC_actv_Payments pt 
WHERE MONTH(pt.EntryDate) = 2 and
YEAR(pt.EntryDate) = 2015 
GROUP BY LicenseKey
')
```

When I run this from SSMS I can see that it returns expected n rows.

However when I'm firing this with the same connection properties to get the data in a DataSet for a C# console application:

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand pcmd= new SqlCommand();
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    OpenConnection();
    pcmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data source=IP adress of the server;Initial Catalog=master; user ID=***; password=***");
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from openquery([oak],'" +
    "SELECT LicenseKey, SUM(PaymentAmount)as Payments" +
    "FROM vw_ODBC_actv_Payments pt " +
    "WHERE MONTH(pt.EntryDate) = 2 and" +
    "YEAR(pt.EntryDate) = 2015" +
    "GROUP BY LicenseKey')";
try
{
    da.SelectCommand = pcmd;
    da.Fill(ds); //here comes the error
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("DBUtils.ExecuteReader():" + ex.Message);
}
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to
>   perform the operation. Now I need to do something with this issue

I'm just learning about openquery. Can anybody guide?

Comment: You're not opening the connection anywhere from the above code.. also you haven't declared `ds`

Comment: @Izzy - it was an code extract from my project. Connection and DataSets are provided by custom functions. My problem is coming when I'm opening the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you're not opening the connection anywhere in your code hence the error. Second clean up your code with the `using` block. So assuming the query works as required you can do something like.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here"))
    {
        string myQuery = "Your Query";
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: It would be a better if you stored the `connectionString` in your `config` file and read it in your code.

Comment: still there is same exception.

Comment: Try `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` in your `connectionString`

Comment: Keyword not supported: `providername`

Comment: Try this.. Create an empty text file on desktop, name it with a `.udl` extension. Once created, double-click on it and you will see a GUI open up to guide you through to build the connection string. Step through it and click on test connection if successful then open the `udl` file up in a text editor and copy the `connectionstring` and paste it in your code

Comment: Izzy - your solution helped me connect to the linked server. I believe there is some restriction - `The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation. Now I need to do something with this issue`

Comment: The error is self explanatory really. How your permissions are set etc you'll need to check and then take it from there. My provided solution answered you orginal question.

Comment: I wanted to keep this question open, many +1s for your help!!